# Insert values from netbeans into mysql database table

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am making a standalone database application in which I use netbeans for java and a mysql database as my server.

Inserting basic values into my database tables fails with an exception "*no jdbc driver found for jdbc:mysql:\localhost\basicinfo*" where in basicinfo is my database name with "info" as my database table. My code:

```
package db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class class1 
{
 public static void main(String[] args )
 {
     try
     {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:\\localhost\basicinfo","root","root");
         Statement stmt=(Statement)con.createStatement();

         String name="Jerome Dcruz";
         String contactno="9773523568";

       String insert="INSERT INTO info VALUES('"+name+"','"+contactno+"');";
       stmt.executeUpdate(insert);



     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage() ,"Error", 1);

     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you placed MySql connector jar into your classpath?

Comment: should i place it in the netbeans project libraries or in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext

Answer (score 0):

you should have the mysql-connector-java driver int C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext

and also place the port number of your database like the following

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basicinfo", "root", "root");
```

you can download the driver from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)

Comment: Whilst this would work, placing jars in the ext folder is not a great solution as it would restrict you from using a different mysql driver in another project should you need to. There are other ways of adding the jar to the classpath that are more flexible, and this would depend on how the project is setup. For example adding dependencies to a Maven or gradle project, or by configuring external libraries in the Netbeans project.

Comment: @Romski Thanks for your suggestion, I will like to know the other way you want to suggest :)

Comment: I have mentioned 3 possibilities, what specifically are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Error Found at (line #15) :

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:\\localhost\basicinfo", "root", "root");
```

Correct it to :

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/basicinfo", "root", "root");
```

Conclusion : There was an error('\' instead of '/') in path and as such, it was impossible to find the specified schema and table.